# Changing TranslationX property in Xamarin Forms Causes UIKit Consistency exception

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

When calling the shared code class from a custom renderer to update the movement of a touch Xamarin throws this exception:

```
UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
```

Here the code that generates the error:

iOS Renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (CustomTabbedPage), typeof (CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]

namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        ...
        public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            ...

            ((CustomTabbedPage)this.Element).updateDragDelta( (double) ( _touchMovedToPoint.X - _touchStartingPoint.X ));

        }

     }

}
```

Shared Class

```
namespace CompanyName
{   
    public class CustomTabbedPage : BaseContentPage
    {
            ...

            public void updateDragDelta(double x)
             {
                 Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                     dragDeltaX = x;
                     this.TranslationX = _lockPosition + dragDeltaX;
                  });
             }
    }
}
```

And the stack trace:

```
  at UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x00023] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1926/6916d0e3/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:71 
  at UIKit.UIViewController.ViewDidLayoutSubviews () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1926/6916d0e3/source/maccore/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:1005 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PlatformRenderer.ViewDidLayoutSubviews () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr)
  at CoreAnimation.CATransaction.Commit () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1926/6916d0e3/source/maccore/src/build/ios/native/CoreAnimation/CATransaction.g.cs:78 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CADisplayLinkTicker.StartThread () [0x0002e] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1926/6916d0e3/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Thread.cs:696
```

I am trying to get the shared code class to know where the touch has moved to. It is also worth noting that the CustomTabbedPageRenderer class also has two UISwipeGestureRecognizers.